# Increment number in ANGULAR doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, increment, angularjs-ng-click

I'm doing an application, there are a virtual keyboard that shows when you click on the `input`. The decrement should be decrement the ng-model `food.Pezzi`, and it works fine. But the increment doesn't work: it add a '1'. Why? [PLUNKER CODE](http://plnkr.co/edit/a9w7aT7kEJXBYD6IAtgU?p=preview)

(the weird thing is that you press Decrement before to press Increment, increment works....)

**Markup**

```
<td>
    <a data-role="button" data-theme="e" ng-click="food.Pezzi = food.Pezzi-1; " 
      style="background-color: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.2); border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27); text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #F3F3F3;color: #333;">
         Decrement
  </a>
</td>
<td>
    <a data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="zero" ng-click='food.Pezzi=food.Pezzi.toString()+"0"'>
        0
    </a>
</td>
<td>
    <a data-role="button" data-theme="e" class="pos" ng-click='food.Pezzi = food.Pezzi + 1' 
      style="background-color: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.2); border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27); text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #F3F3F3;color: #333;">
        Increment
      </a>
</td>
```

Thank you in advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to `var itemToClone = { "Selection": "", "Pezzi": 0 };` instead of `var itemToClone = { "Selection": "", "Pezzi": "" };`. You are initializing with an empty string to it's appending to the string instead of adding a number.

Same goes at other places. You have to type cast the string using `parseInt` after you are modifying your input.

**Update**

That weired. Let's add a method in your controller like this:

```
$scope.inc = function(food) {
    food.Pezzi = food.Pezzi || "0"
    food.Pezzi = parseInt(food.Pezzi.toString()) + 1;
};
```

Now, modify your increment button's `ng-click` to like this: `ng-click="inc(food)"`

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work, it clears all and write "1" ! http://plnkr.co/edit/XbLYCLtwjAlUEpdkk2Pg?p=preview

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please check it out. You can do the same for the decrement button.

Comment: Also, let me know if your plunkr does not work. I'll share my edits.

Comment: It works very fine, thank you a loot! p.s. what does food.Pezzi || "0" means?

Comment: Glad, this works. Feel free to accept the answer. `food.Pezzi || "0"` means if there is an `undefined`, `null` or `0` value in the `food.Pezzi` then it will initialize it with the `"0"` (handling edge condition).

Answer (score 2):

First of all you're using AngularJS in a bad way, never put Business Logic in your views.

By the way, your bug depends on the **type** of the property **Pezzi**, for mathematical operation you need to work with numbers, but, in javascript, the **+** operator is used even for string concatenation... have a look on the two following examples: (the first is correct, the second, because loses the type, in addition performs a string concatenation instead of a sum).

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    var vm = $scope;
  
    vm.food = { pezzi: 0 };
    
    vm.increment = function() { vm.food.pezzi += 1; };
    vm.decrement = function() { if(vm.food.pezzi > 0) vm.food.pezzi -= 1;   };
    vm.reset = function() { vm.food.pezzi = 0; };

    vm.getType = function() {
      return typeof vm.food.pezzi;
    }
    
      
    vm.foodCloned = { pezzi: 0 + '' };
    
    vm.incrementCloned = function() { vm.foodCloned.pezzi += 1 + ''; };
    vm.decrementCloned = function() { vm.foodCloned.pezzi -= 1 + ''; };
    vm.resetCloned = function() { vm.foodCloned.pezzi = 0 + ''; };

    vm.getClonedType = function() {
      return typeof vm.foodCloned.pezzi;
    }
    
  })
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<article ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    
    <button ng-click="decrement($event)">Decrement</button>
    <button ng-click="increment($event)">Increment</button>
    <button ng-click="reset($event)">Reset</button>
    
    
    <h1 ng-bind="food | json"></h1>
    <div ng-bind="getType()"></div>
    <hr><hr>
    
    
    <button ng-click="decrementCloned($event)">Decrement</button>
    <button ng-click="incrementCloned($event)">Increment</button>
    <button ng-click="resetCloned($event)">Reset</button>
    
    
    <h1 ng-bind="foodCloned | json"></h1>
    <div ng-bind="getClonedType()"></div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: This is really beautiful code. very clean and neat too!!